# Rails App - how to switch Heroku hosting

Tags: heroku

I have a copy of a rails app that I want to set up with new Heroku hosting. How do I delete the old Heroku hosting and set up anew?

Answer (score 0):

You can destroy an application from your [control panel](https://dashboard.heroku.com/). Go to the *application page > settings*, scroll down to the bottom and follow the instructions in the section *Delete App*.

[image]

Then you will need to delete the remote entry from your git repo. Assuming you called it `heroku`

```
$ git remote remove heroku
```

You can also remove the app from the command line from inside your app.

```
$ heroku apps:destroy
```

See

```
$ heroku help apps
apps:create [NAME]    #  create a new app
apps:destroy          #  permanently destroy an app
apps:info             #  show detailed app information
apps:join --app APP   #  add yourself to an organization app
apps:leave --app APP  #  remove yourself from an organization app
apps:lock             #  lock an organization app to restrict access
apps:open             #  open the app in a web browser
apps:rename NEWNAME   #  rename the app
apps:unlock           #  unlock an organization app so that any org member can join it
```

Then use

```
$ heroku apps:create
```

to create the new app from inside your Rails app folder.